# Gatsby: Navigation links to top level route on subpages (created with createPage) not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, gatsby

This might be a rookie question, however I couldn't really find a solution to this while searching the forum:

I have a page 'careers' created through the pages folder (file name careers.js with corresponding slug /careers) and several subpages of careers created with the createPages API in the file gatsby-node.js like so:

```
    result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
        const department = node.frontmatter.department
        const slug = node.frontmatter.slug
        const path = '/careers/${department}/${slug}'

         createPage({
             path,
             component: careerPositionTemplate,
              context: {
                  slug,
              },
         })
    })
```

My problem now is that once I am on a slug of a subpage (i.e. /careers/engineering/position-engineer) the navigation links in my header and footer to /careers/ don't work. Once I'm on any route that contains the top-level route /careers/ the link to /careers/ in the navigation gets rendered without a href:

In the Navigation.js file the Link is defined as:

```
    <Link activeClassName="active" to="/careers" onClick={handleCloseOnTimeout}>
         <Button color="dark" size="md">Career</Button>
    </Link>
```

On route /careers/engineering/position-engineer the back link to /careers/ doesn't work. The Output in the header and footer is:

```
   <a class="d-flex align-items-center ml-2">
       <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">Career</button>
    </a>
```

On route /about/ without the top level route /careers/ the link is rendered with a href as I want it:

```
  <a class="d-flex align-items-center ml-2" href="/careers">
     <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">Career</button>
   </a>
```

I already tried a plugin [gatsby-plugin-exact-client-paths](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-exact-client-paths), however, that plugin throws errors after installing. So I couldn't test whether it would solve my problem. After trying multiple other things with client-side routes and manually setting up routing with reach router in vain I'm now desperate enough to post this question here. Don't know if it has been answered somewhere else here already - I'm just would be grateful for any help.

#### Environment (if relevant)

```
  System:
    OS: Windows 10
    Shell: Command Prompt, Powershell
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.16.2
    npm: 6.14.4
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 81.0.4044.138 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit)
npmPackages:
    "gatsby": "2.21.33",
    "gatsby-image": "2.4.3",
    "gatsby-plugin-alias-imports": "^1.0.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-anchor-links": "1.1.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-compile-es6-packages": "^2.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "2.4.3",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "3.2.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-postcss": "2.3.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "3.3.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-svg": "^3.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "2.3.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "2.6.3",
    "gatsby-plugin-transition-link": "^1.18.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "2.3.3",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "2.8.8",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "2.5.2",
    "node-sass": "4.14.1",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem after reconstructing the problem in a minimal reproduction app. The Link component has been rewritten by a custom Link component and the route matching of the custom Link component was not done properly / was buggy. That's why the links were not working properly on subpages / subroutes.